# linq ExecuteQuery array parameter

Tags: c#, linq

I need use a query like

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE field IN (1,2,3)
```

I c# use this

```
var data = context.ExecuteQuery<Some>( "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE field IN {0}", arrayParam ); //for example arrayParam has 1,2,3
```

When I used this, works fine

```
 var data = context.ExecuteQuery<Some>( "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE field = {0}", 1);
```

But in with param crash

as passing the array of parameters?

NOTE: The real query is It is much more complex, for this reason use native query instead linq

Comment: There's no such thing unfortunately, you will have to pass each parameter separately using named parameters, or use string concatenation

Comment: "Where(field = 1 or field = 2 or field = 3 or field = 4)"  You can easily generate the where clause string in C#.   Lot of way of doing this.  Can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you verify your array before passing it as a SQL param (to prevent SQL injection), you can do something like this:

```
var data = context.ExecuteQuery<Some>( "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE field IN ({0})", string.Join(",",arrayParam.Select(n=>n.ToString())));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what @Marcin Zablocki says, or you can construct a string with your entire query and call ExecuteQuery without any param like this:

```
var query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE field IN ({0})", string.Join(",", arrayParam.Select(n => n.ToString())));

var data = context.ExecuteQuery<Some>(query);
```